# How to define a global variable that is created via a for loop inside another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, tkinter, global-variables

I am getting the error

> NameError: global name 'spinbox_0' is not defined

when I try to fetch the value from one of my Tkinter spinboxes and print it out. The spinbox is located within another function and I would define it if possible, however I don't know how to in this instance because the names and number of spinboxes is created by a for loop depending on how long the subject list is.

I think it will be easier to just post the code for debugging. The error code shows when the `Button two` button is pressed.

At the moment I would just like to retrieve that `spinbox_0` value and print it. Afterwards I will work on fetching all of the spinbox values with another loop.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Spinbox, Label

## Create a window
window = Tk()

## Give the window a title
window.title('Tester')

names = ['Name 1','Name 2','Name 3','Name 4','Name 5','Name 6','Name 7']

## Define the actions for when button one is pushed
def button1():
    print "Button one pushed"
## Create the Spinboxes for each name in the list
    spinbox_list = []
    spinbox_grid_list = []
    for number, name in enumerate(names):
        spinbox = 'spinbox_' + str(number) + ' = Spinbox(window, width = 3, from_=0, to=10)'
        spinbox_grid = 'spinbox_' + str(number) + '.grid(padx = 0, pady = 0, row = 13, column = '+ str(number) +')'
        spinbox_list.append(spinbox)
        spinbox_grid_list.append(spinbox_grid)
        spinbox_option = {'spinbox_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(spinbox_list)}
    spinbox_option_string = '\n'.join(spinbox_option.values())
    spinbox_grid_option = {'spinbox_grid_{}'.format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(spinbox_grid_list)}
    spinbox_grid_option_string = '\n'.join(spinbox_grid_option.values())
    exec(spinbox_option_string)
    exec(spinbox_grid_option_string)
## Create a second button
    button_two = Button(window, text = 'Button two', command = button2, width = 20)
    button_two.grid(pady = 10, padx = 2, row = 14, columnspan = 9, sticky = "S") 

## Define the actions for when button two is pushed (print the spinbox values)
def button2():
    print 'spinbox_0 = ' + (spinbox_0.get())
    ## spinbox_0 is Just an example. I need all spinboxes to print out their
    ## values here somehow

button_one = Button(window, text = 'Button one', command = button1, width = 20)
button_one.grid(pady = 2, padx = 2, row = 1, columnspan = 9, sticky = 'S')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: "I think it will be easier to just post the code for debugging." More specifically, you should post a [mcve].

Comment: This is the broken down version, as small as needed for it to run

Comment: you have created spinbox list and you are not using it function button2, you're directly trying to access one of the elements in the list. Make the list global and access the item in the list

Comment: @Keval Yes, that's what my answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidestepping the fact that global variables are a Bad Idea™, here's a way to do it. Make your global variable, then don't reassign it inside the function. You can now loop over that in your `button2` function. Since you want the Spinbox object, not its description, save *that*.

* BTW, by avoiding `exec`, you can severely simplify your `button1` function.

```
spinboxes = []


# Define the actions for when button one is pushed
def button1():
    print "Button one pushed"
    # Create the Spinboxes for each name in the list
    spinbox_grid_list = []
    for number, name in enumerate(names):
        spinboxes.append(Spinbox(window, width=3, from_=0, to=10))
        spinboxes[number].grid(padx=0, pady=0, row=13, column=number)
    button_two = Button(window, text='Button two', command=button2, width=20)
    button_two.grid(pady=10, padx=2, row=14, columnspan=9, sticky="S")

# Define the actions for when button two is pushed (print the spinbox values)
def button2():
    for i, spinbox in enumerate(spinboxes):
        print 'spinbox_{} = '.format(i) + (spinbox.get())
```

I assume that `button1` is only ever called once. Otherwise, this will keep adding new `spinbox`es to the global list every time it's pressed. To get around that:

```
def button1():
    print "Button one pushed"

    global spinboxes
    spinboxes = []
    ...
```

We use the `global` keyword to let us reassign the global object, clearing it out every time the function is called.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting a different error now: "File "C:/Users/thejo/Dropbox/Uni/IFB104/Test.py", line 35, in button2
    print 'spinbox_{} = '.format(i) + (spinbox.get())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'" Any ideas on what to do with this?

Comment: Yeah, I caught that and edited my response. It comes from the fact that you're calling `get` on a string. Just use the string's value.

Comment: Ah I see it is just printing my spinbox label values, the ones I used in order to create the actual spinboxes in the window. I have to 'get' the numerical values entered into the spinboxes form the Tkinter window.

Comment: Is that the behavior you intended, or is something missing?

Comment: No I am trying to get the value from the actual boxes in the Tkinter window and print them all. It appears that Spinbox has to start with a capital. I have tried: "def button2():
    for i in spinbox_list:
        print Spinbox.get()"
But I get the error: "unbound method get() must be called with Spinbox instance as first argument (got nothing instead)"

Comment: Yeah, `Spinbox` is just the class, rather than a specific spinbox. I see what you're going for now; I've updated my answer to let you access the spinbox objects themselves.

Comment: Yes I have accepted the answer but unfortunately I don't have the reputation to up-vote just yet, sorry about that.